# How to find which table has layer in mapinfo?

Tags: cartography, mapinfo, mapbasic

Is it possible to find if table has layer Or print list of layers?
 Edit::
I have a table when I selete some data from table like:

```
Select * from earth where population >100
```

Then it create new table but if want to hide layer closing table would not work so to hide layer I need to know table that are used to create layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you want to be able to find out in MapBasic what table a query is based on.

In your queries I would advise adding the into clause to the end of the select statement so you know what the table name is you are dealing with. For eg.

```
Select * from earth where population >100 into qryName
```

To determine whether a table is a query or not, you can use the following:

```
Print TableInfo(qryName, TAB_INFO_TYPE)
```

If this returns 1 its a base table and if it returns 2 the table is a query.

If the layer is a query, then you can use

```
Print TableInfo(qryName, TAB_INFO_MAPPABLE_TABLE)
```

This will tell you which layer the query is based on. But it only works with mappable queries. This is from the MapBasic reference guide:

> String result indicating the name of
>   the table containing graphical
>   objects. Use this code when you are
>   working with a table that is actually
>   a relational join of two other tables,
>   and you need to know the name of the
>   base table that contains the graphical
>   objects.

I think for you case this should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @James Do you mean a query(table) is layer if it is mappable ?

Comment: In MapInfo you use tables. Tables can be mappable (ie have spatial data). If you add a mappable table to a map window, it becomes a layer in that map window. Query's that have mappable data can also be added as layers to a map window. The layer in the map window will still be based on a MapInfo table.

Answer (score 0):

Use Table List
via Layer Control
[image]